# Can I get MySQL FULLTEXT ranks in [0; 1] range?

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, range, rank

I am implementing something like autosuggest for arbitrary text/phrases. I want to provide to user some **absolute** relevance, not just rank of found items relatively to each other. 
I.e., if some rows in DB contain entered text in exact form and order, I need a rank around "1".

For example, lets search for "**I like fruits**":

- for row with content "For sure **I like fruits** and vegitables" I expect rank to be **1** or a bit less.
- for row with content "**I like** fresh **fruits**" I expect results less then 1 but still quite high, like **0.7**.

Can this be done with MySQL and FULLTEXT ?
Instead of [0,1] I am getting values like 2.7 or 1.2 or even 0.6 for full match. What's wrong with it?

Here is my test table:

**Table data:**

```
id  text
1   Lorem ipsum dolor
2   You can search an index, and organize and present search results.
3   The Search API can index any number of documents.
4   Each field has a name and a type.
5   Each field is required.
7   Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. 
8   Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. 
9   Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. 
10  Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus.
```

**Query 1:**

```
SET @str := 'Lorem ipsum dolor';
SELECT id, TEXT, MATCH (TEXT) AGAINST (@str) rank FROM test WHERE MATCH (TEXT) AGAINST (@str);
```

->

```
 id text    rank
 1  Lorem ipsum dolor   1.280059814453125
```

What this '1.28' means? Would be nice to have '1' here.

**Query 2:**

```
SET @str := 'Each field is required.';
SELECT id, TEXT, MATCH (TEXT) AGAINST (@str) rank FROM test WHERE MATCH (TEXT) AGAINST (@str);
```

->

```
 id text    rank
 5  Each field is required. 1.7639520168304443
 4  Each field has a name and a type.   0.8533731698989868
```

One more full match, I expect '1' here too.

**Query 3:**

```
SET @str := 'Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu';
SELECT id, TEXT, MATCH (TEXT) AGAINST (@str) rank FROM test WHERE MATCH (TEXT) AGAINST (@str);
```

->

```
id  text    rank
8   Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.  3.5851094722747803
9   Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi.     0.4266865849494934
```

Also full match, and misterious '3.58' is returned.

I don't need precise numbers, just ones between [0,1], so that I can figure out if there is a full (or almost full) match. If result fully contains searched string I need something around 0.8..1. Or maybe it is just a wrong tool? FULLTEXT actually is not so full text, cause I can't figure out was it fully matched or not.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL uses [an n-dimensional vector product with some fudge factors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/full-text-search.html) to produce relevance values for full-text matches, which means that the values can't be normalized in general fashion beyond a given dataset and query. (Then again, why would you need them to be? Similar queries on the same dataset will already produce similar relevance values, and normalization among results of dissimilar queries wouldn't help anything, anyway.)

That said, there's nothing stopping you from normalizing rank values yourself, within the set of results returned from a query, using a simple calculation per row:

```
row_normalized_rank = row_returned_rank / highest_returned_rank
```

This will require two scans of the resultset, one to identify the highest returned rank value and another to normalize each row's rank value against the highest returned; you could probably do it with a sufficiently godawful nested query, but you're probably better off doing it in code.

You can also add a fudge factor yourself, to improve ranking for exact matches; consider an absolute rank adjustment such as:

```
SELECT id, text, (MATCH (text) AGAINST (@str) +
                  IF(text LIKE CONCAT("%", @str, "%"), 1, -1)) AS rank
FROM test
WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST (@str);
```

or an expansion of magnitude such as:

```
SET @fudge := 2;
SELECT id, text, (MATCH (text) AGAINST (@str) *
                  IF(text LIKE CONCAT("%", @str, "%"), @fudge, 1/@fudge)) AS rank
FROM test
WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST (@str);
```

Adjust to taste, of course, but this should help to give you something more like what you're looking for in terms of ranking behavior.

Comment: Thanks, and great idea with `@fedge` approach in a single query! It does not solve my problem, but allows to ensure that I don't miss most relevant results. 

I need [0,1] range because: 1) I don't want to show results with low relevance at all 2) I want to provide to user additional hints/highlighting/recommendation mark for most relevant results (0.7 to 1 for example), not just most ranked one. User Experience is top priority for me.

Comment: @vladimir83 Sure -- I'm not discounting your purpose, so much as trying to point out how you can probably achieve the result you need with a little fudging and post-processing. How would the solution need to change to meet your requirement? (I think I must be misreading something in your explanation, because it's still not clear to me what's missing.)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's impossible to normalize rank to [0,1] with MySQL only. By normalizing to [0,1] I mean getting values close to 1 for (almost) full matching rows, not just for rows with highest rank. For example, if I search for `"one apple, two oranges"` I may get a single row like `"one two three"`. Using formula  `rank=row_rank/highest_rank` I'll get rank=1 in this case. But it is not a full match. I would rather expect value around 0.5 or less (half of searched words were found).

Also I've looked into Lucene and Sphinx. There are few rankers, but seems that definition of rank=1 may completely depend on application requirements. For example, I need rank=1 if searched phrase is fully contained in DB, but someone may expect it to be 1 when searched phrase matches entire content in DB.

---

So, I solved the issue by doing it **in three steps**:

**1. Get top 100 ranked rows from DB using FULLTEXT and `x2/fudge` approach suggested by Aaron:**

```
SELECT id, TEXT, (MATCH (TEXT) AGAINST (@str) *
                  IF(TEXT LIKE CONCAT("%", @str, "%"), 2, 1)) AS rank
FROM test
WHERE MATCH (TEXT) AGAINST (@str) ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 100;
```

This does all heavy job of retrieving most relevant rows, reducing amount of data for the next step. In fact rank value from MySQL is completely ignored.

**2. For each of 100 rows calculate normalized rank programmatically on Java/Groovy side, based on application requirements (as [0,1] range)**

This was quite challenging, but I was able to create relatively straightforward algorithm based on simple math formulas and few rules. After some optimization it took about 6ms to calculate ranks against all 100 rows.

**3. Sort the result by new rank, show top 10 results to user.**

I do not show results with rank < 0.5, and in UI I additionally emphasise on results with high ranks (0.8-1)

I tested it and it works quite well. However, for some cases FULLTEXT search from step #1 does not return results at all. This happens when searched phrase is in general present in DB, but few word endings are different. My ranking algorithm may evaluate it as 0.3-0.7 rank, but it just does not come from step #1. So, for now I'll keep with this approach, but later may consider replacing MySQL with something other (maybe Lucene) in step #1.